# How to tell Pool to use a certain number of cores per process?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pool

I'm using `multiprocessing.Pool` to parallelise some computation in a project. How can I tell Pool to use n (eg. 4) cores per parallel process?

Say I have 8 cores. Will this code make sure that each parallel process is running on 4 cores?

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool

def fun(in):
    print(in)

pool = Pool(2)
pool.map(fun, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
```

Comment: Usually a process uses one core. The parameter to `Pool` is how many Processes it will create.

Comment: The idea of the code was that if I have 2 threads running on an 8 cores computer the workload will be spread evenly and therefore each thread could be spread on 4 cores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`multiprocessing.Pool` will not create multiple threads per process, but multiple single-threaded processes. "Parallel processes" means multiple processes that run in parallel, not single processes that are somehow internally parallel.

Each process in a `multiprocessing.Pool` will run on exactly one core at a time, so you should create as many processes as you want cores to be utilised - in this case if you want to potentially utilise all eight cores, you want eight processes in the pool:

```py
pool = Pool(8)
```

You can also not pass an argument at all, and `Pool` will automatically allocate as many processes as you have CPU cores.

[Documentation for `multiprocessing.Pool`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool):

> *processes* is the number of worker processes to use. If *processes* is `None` then the number returned by [`os.cpu_count()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.cpu_count) is used.

Note, however, that you cannot actually tell `Pool` to use a specific core or specific amount of cores - that decision is made by your operating system, which will usually try to allocate workloads evenly across cores.

Comment: Thank you! More specifically my project is about training multiple neural networks at once with keras.
My question arises from the fact that I noticed that if I run a training with 4 cores (on a cluster in which I can select how many cores my code uses) it much faster then any other number of cores. So my objective was to have 4 cores available for each thread (and if possible force each thread to use only 4 cores). 
From what you said, if the os allocates the workload evenly i just need to have n_cores/4 threads.

Comment: @AlbertoRolandi I want to clarify that `Pool` doesn't allow a scenario where you schedule a single task in the pool and it gets executed on eg. four cores. Instead what you want to do is to schedule *four* tasks in the pool, and each of those can be executed on a separate core. Your comment reads to me like you think a `Pool(2)` on a 8-core system will use 4 threads per process, which is not how `Pool` works. `Pool(2)` cannot utilise more than 2 cores.

Comment: @AlbertoRolandi  When I say "allocate workloads evenly", I mean when you create a thread it will probably be executed on the core with the least load. Example: You have 4 cores. When you create 4 single-thread processes, it is likely that they'll each be executed on a different core because that way no cores are free and each process gets a full core. If you created 2 single-threaded processes instead, those would be allocated to 2 cores, and the other 2 cores would be left idle, doing nothing.

Comment: You were correct, I understood that a thread could use more than one core. Now I understand what you meant. I also noticed this by experiment, it worked faster If I gave it n threads for n cores.
Do you happen to know any library that would allow me to select how many cores uses a thread?

Answer (score 0):

No, your code will allow `Pool` to create two processes (they use one core each) and `map()` will process your collection of items through the designated function in two streams.

I think you might mean:

```
pool = Pool(4)
```

This will mean that your `fun` will be running on 4 cores simultaneously.